# grunt blocked by Windows 7 group policy

Tags: windows, gruntjs

I'm trying to build the jQuery slider plugin from [here](https://github.com/abdavid/jslider), but I can't run grunt in order to do so. When I try using the Windows command prompt (as admin) from the project's root directory, I get the error: "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, please contact your system administrator." I'm running Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: So, did you contact your system administrator?

Comment: I am the system admin. I have an admin account. I checked the local group policy and can't find where it would be blocked.

Comment: Open Group Policy Editor and search manually through every entry to find it so you can remove it. As far as I know, there's no automated search. Alternatively, you could run `gpresult /h gpreport` to get a report, and then grep through it.

Comment: I created the report and searched through it, but didn't find it.